# Windows form crash without any error, just error in Event log

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms

I have problem with windows forms and multithreading. It is working for few minutes then crash without any error:

In event log I can find this:

```
- <Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
- <System>
  <Provider Name="Application Error" /> 
  <EventID Qualifiers="0">1000</EventID> 
  <Level>2</Level> 
  <Task>100</Task> 
  <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords> 
  <TimeCreated SystemTime="2013-12-26T10:12:47.000000000Z" /> 
  <EventRecordID>23018</EventRecordID> 
  <Channel>Application</Channel> 
  <Computer>Mitja-Notebook</Computer> 
  <Security /> 
  </System>
- <EventData>
  <Data>NCrawler.Demo.exe</Data> 
  <Data>3.0.0.0</Data> 
  <Data>52bc0008</Data> 
  <Data>libcef.DLL</Data> 
  <Data>3.1650.1544.0</Data> 
  <Data>52a42238</Data> 
  <Data>c0000005</Data> 
  <Data>0014bd08</Data> 
  <Data>16b0</Data> 
  <Data>01cf0222620ef60a</Data> 
  <Data>D:\PROJEKTI\crawler\WebCrawlerSuite\NCrawler\NCrawler.Demo\bin\Debug\NCrawler.Demo.exe</Data> 
  <Data>D:\PROJEKTI\crawler\WebCrawlerSuite\NCrawler\NCrawler.Demo\bin\Debug\libcef.DLL</Data> 
  <Data>4487f3b0-6e16-11e3-a4f2-824ba6d84ade</Data> 
  </EventData>
  </Event>
```

and

```
Wrong program name: NCrawler.Demo.exe, version: 3.0.0.0, timestamp: 0x52bc0008
Wrong module name: libcef.DLL, version: 3.1650.1544.0, timestamp: 0x52a42238
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Wrong path: D:\PROJEKTI\crawler\WebCrawlerSuite\NCrawler\NCrawler.Demo\bin\Debug\NCrawler.Demo.exe
Wrong module path: D:\PROJEKTI\crawler\WebCrawlerSuite\NCrawler\NCrawler.Demo\bin\Debug\libcef.DLL
```

What Can i do? How to find the real problem and solve it.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: You've had enough misery with Chromium Embedded Framework I'd say.  Clearly you have no idea how to debug native code, it is time you cut your losses and get rid of it.

Comment: @Hans maybe you right. Another question is why to debug native code? Nativ code should work...

Answer (score 1):

http://www.updatexp.com/0xC0000005.html

the Exception code 0xC0000005 Access Violation

A quick scan of the online technical forums and blogs reveal folks asking for help with this windows error. Your question may be the same as this typical request:

"An application error has occurred and an application error log is being generated. Exception: access violation (0xC0000005), Address"

The error 0xC0000005 is generated by an illegal "memory access violation". This can be caused by anything from faulty RAM, an incorrect/corrupt device driver, poorly written/updated software and more commonly under Windows XP Service pack 2, malware/adware installations.

Usually you get this error message when performing a specific task, and if that happens you need to check the corresponding 3rd party's website/support department to see if they are aware of the problem

..a while back Symantec Antivirus caused the 0xC0000005 error with an additional message about a file called SAVRT.SYS . A simple software update to the Symantec Antivirus cured the problem.